# ServiceNow Flow Designer - Invalid property id error

Tags: javascript, null, servicenow

The error: invalid property id (Process Automation.65fea5d993050210f7db35918bba1034.InlineScript_assignment_groupa1fea5d9f5050210d8e77cda73f14762; line 10)

The Code:
// Get the incident category
var category = current.category;

```
// Define a map to store category-to-group
var assignmentMap = {
  "Hardware": "Hardware",
  "Software": "Software",
  "Network": "Network",
  "Inquiry/Help": "Help Desk",
  null: "Incident Management",
};

// Does the category exists in the map
var assignedGroup = assignmentMap[category];

// Assign the group to the incident if found
if (assignedGroup) {
  current.assignment_group = assignedGroup;
} else {

  gs.info ("no assignment for " +category);
}

// Update the incident record
current.update();
```

I am expecting that assignment groups get associated with categories at creation or update of records.

Comment: what is the value of `category`? oh, is `var category = current.category;` the cause of the error?

Comment: the forms have been set and have different categories. var category pulls the current category the incident has. Once the current.category hits an empty category it throws an error.